# Module import works on interpreter but not on a script

Tags: python, import, interpreter, elementtree

i was beggining to follow a tutorial on elementtree in this site http://www.bigfatalien.com/?p=223 so as usual i typed the reference scripts on the interpreter and i went

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
```

And the interpreter run that command just fine and using "xml" in the intrepreter with no problems my IDE even showed the members of that class on the autocomplete but as soon as i typed the exact same line on a script and tried to run it, it say

> object has no attribute 'etree'

, this line works:

```
import xml
```

But if i add:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree = xml
```

And try to run that script that doesnt work, i tried with my IDE (pyscripter) and with IDLE, same behaviour.
Whats going on here, whats this behavior, i never read it mentioned on any of the "how to import in python" tutorials or books. I feel i'm missing something obvious.

Update with the error messages requested

Ran the provided lines from IDLE 2.6

```
2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[u'C:\\Users\\grillermo\\Desktop', 'C:\\Program Files\\PyScripter\\Lib\\rpyc-python2x.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\dropbox_client-1.0-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-2.1.6-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\poster-0.8.1-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth-1.0.1-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.0.0-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python26\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python26', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']
2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[u'C:\\Users\\grillermo\\Desktop', 'C:\\Program Files\\PyScripter\\Lib\\rpyc-python2x.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\dropbox_client-1.0-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-2.1.6-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\poster-0.8.1-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth-1.0.1-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.0.0-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python26\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python26', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grillermo\Desktop\xml.py", line 4, in <module>
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
  File "C:\Users\grillermo\Desktop\xml.py", line 4, in <module>
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
```

The interpreter

```
C:\>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
>>> print et.__file__
C:\Python26\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc
>>>
```

Comment: Bingo! """File "C:\Users\grillermo\Desktop\xml.py", line 4, in <module>""" -- see my answer.

Comment: Python can import from your current directory. Since you named your file xml.py, and it's in IDLE's current directory, that is what was found first as the base part of `xml.etree`. Your module doesn't have etree in it.

Comment: thanks guys i would never had thought that you could import the same script you are running.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A really silly question: did you name your script file `xml.py`? If so, DON'T DO THAT ... `import xml.anything` will be looking in your script file! It's never a good idea to give a script file the same name as a module that you are going to import.

**Update** Tracebacks are your friends. Lead to read them carefully. If you don't know how to read them, **include the traceback in your question**.

I'm betting that yours will look very similar to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml.py", line 4, in <module>
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
  File "C:\junk\xml.py", line 4, in <module> #### here's the culprit ####
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
```

Otherwise:

Set up a script containing only the following lines:

```
import sys
print sys.version
print sys.path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
print et.__file__
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
print xml.__file__
```

run it, and show all the output ... copy/paste into an edit of your question.

Repeat the following interpreter session on your computer, and report what is printed:

```
C:\junk>\python26\python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
>>> print et.__file__
C:\python26\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc
>>>
```

Comment: +1, I think you have it, John. Pity I had to go shopping, you nutted it out while I was away :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
```

you are bringing in the `xml.etree.ElementTree` "object" and calling it `xml`.

That doesn't appear to be the case in your second version. In that, you import the `xml` as `xml` and then assign the wrong way around:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree = xml
```

That appears to be replacing the `ElementTree` object with a reference to the top-level `xml`, probably not what you wanted. I'd be tempted to say that:

```
xml = xml.etree.ElementTree
```

would be the more accurate way but I'm not sure if that's going to cause problems with naming.

In any case, I can't see what's actually *wrong* with your `import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml` version It appears to do exactly what you want (and works fine in scripts for me).

Comment: if i do "import xml.etree.ElementTree" in the interpreter it works but if i paste the exact same line on a script it sends the error "No module named etree.ElementTree"

Comment: I have no trouble with a script holding just the line `import xml.etree.ElementTree` in 2.5.2. Are you sure you're running a 2.5+ version from the script? Use 'import sys`, `print sys.version` to find out.

Comment: 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: @Guillermo: Look in C:\Python26\Lib\xml ... do you see a directory called `etree`? If so, what are its contents? Are you sure that that version 2.6.6 banner came from a script that then failed to import xml.etree.ElementTree?

Comment: Yeah, just checked i see the tree directory, and i tried print sys.version on the same script that failed, same output(yeah it could be a python interpreter version problem since i keep 3 python versions)